# Java - check intersection of two strings

Tags: java, string

I'm having a way to check for insection of two strings, which are all characters, seperated by a comma.

```
if(brauen[p] > 35){
                m1 = "A, S";
            }else if(brauen[p] <=35 && brauen[p]>20){
                m1 = "T";
            }else{
                m1 = "W";
            }
            if(mund[p] > 50){
                m2 = "S";
            }else{
                m2 = "T, W, E";
            }
            if(augen[p] > 25){
                m3 = "A, S";
            }else{
                m3 = "T, V, E";
            }

            List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList(m1.split(","));
            List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList(m2.split(","));
            List<String> l3 = Arrays.asList(m3.split(","));
            List<String> result = l1.stream().filter(l2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
            resultString = String.join(",", result);
            System.out.println(resultString);
```

The code is in a for loop, iterating over an array.

What I don't understand now: If i define single strings (like above the defintion of the three lists), like so:

```
 String s1 = "T,V,E";
 String s2 = "T,W,E";
```

then its working and the result is `T,E`, as excepted.

But with the code I provided its not working, and I only get the string `T` or an empty string as result.

The weird thing: `l1` and `l2` are defined correctly, if I just print those after the definition, the values are correct, and the intersections should be `W` and `S` too.

So I really can't find any problem about it, if I basically define the same strings above, like I said, so:

```
String s1 = "T,V,E";
 String s2 = "T,W,E";
```

or

```
String s1 = "A,S";
 String s2 = "S";
```

then its working, but if I use the Lists that get the values from `m1` and `m2` it's not working, although the list looks exactly the same.

Can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the letters into a `Collection` of some description (could be `List`, could be `Set` if you want to discard duplicates):

```
Set<String> first = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s1.split(","));
Set<String> second = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s2.split(","));
```

Then just remove all the elements from `first` that aren't in `second` (or, another way to look at it, retain only the elements in `first` which are in `second`):

```
first.retainAll(second);
```

Now join them again:

```
String intersection = String.join(",", first);
```

Comment: It should be perfect .

Comment: So instead of a list, use a Set?

Comment: @nameless you can use a `List`; it doesn't really matter. It would work the same (except that `Set` would discard repeats).

Comment: When I try to use the set, it says `Cannot resolve the constructor`, whats the problem?

Comment: @AndyTurner I am 1 min 33 seconds late :(

Comment: @tobias_k why? `LHS` preserves insertion order.

Comment: Somehow, I still get the same result as before, but I still only get `T` or an empty string as result, not what it should be...

Comment: @AndyTurner You are right, did not see the specific `Set` type. Ignore my previous comment. Still does not take multiplicities into account, should that matter, but neither does OP's original code.

Comment: @nameless Check your strings. Maybe there is a space or newline at the end of one of the strings, thus comparing `"E"` and `"E "`?

Comment: @nameless use `split(", ")` or `split(",\\s+")` if you want to ignore the space after the comma.

Comment: @AndyTurner absolutely, that was the problem I didn't notice, I completely forgot about the whitespace, that why it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

If there is no specific requirement to use `for` loop with array then I would use Collections and library methods to achieve this, e.g.:

```
String s1 = "T,V,E";
String s2 = "T,W,E";

List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s1.split(",")));
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s2.split(",")));

list1.retainAll(list2);
System.out.println(String.join(",", list1));
```

Comment: Somehow I'm getting an error with the `retainAll`, its saying `exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.retainAll(AbstractCollection.java:410)
 at Main.main(Main.java:114)`

Comment: @nameless that's because you're not doing the `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))` bit. You're just doing `Arrays.asList(...)`.

Comment: Looks like you are not wrapping `Arrays.asList` into a new constructor (e.g. `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList..`. `Arrays.asList` returns an immutable list and hence, that Exception.

Comment: @AndyTurner again, I am 37 seconds late, taking your lead to 2 minutes and 7 seconds.

Comment: just commeted on @AndyTurner

Comment: @nameless you can update the question with the approach you tried and results, that will help us help you better..